# How to get all possible permutation matrices of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, permutation

I need to create all possible permutation matrices for a matrix where every permutation matrix contains only one 1 in each column and each row, and 0 in all other places.

For example, below example in (1) is all possible permutation matrices for 2x2 matrix  and in (2) is a all possible permutation matrices for 3x3 matrix and so on

[image: Matrices]

So how can I get these matrices of a matrix NxN in MATLAB and store them into one three-dimensional matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my solution, using [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) (tested with Octave 5.2.0 and MATLAB Online):

```matlab
n = 3;

% Get all permutations of length n
p = perms(1:n);

% Number of permutations
n_p = size(p, 1);

% Set up indices, where to set elements to 1
p = p + (0:n:n^2-1) + (0:n^2:n^2*n_p-1).';

% Set up indices, where to set elements to 1 (for MATLAB R2016a and before)
%p = bsxfun(@plus, bsxfun(@plus, p, (0:n:n^2-1)), (0:n^2:n^2*n_p-1).');

% Initialize 3-dimensional matrix
a = zeros(n, n, n_p);

% Set proper elements to 1 
a(p) = 1
```

The output for `n = 3`:

```
a =

ans(:,:,1) =

   0   0   1
   0   1   0
   1   0   0

ans(:,:,2) =

   0   1   0
   0   0   1
   1   0   0

ans(:,:,3) =

   0   0   1
   1   0   0
   0   1   0

ans(:,:,4) =

   0   1   0
   1   0   0
   0   0   1

ans(:,:,5) =

   1   0   0
   0   0   1
   0   1   0

ans(:,:,6) =

   1   0   0
   0   1   0
   0   0   1
```

Comment: you beat me to it!

Comment: @Ander Waiting for Luis' superior one-liner to solve that. ;-)

Comment: @HansHirse When setting n = 64 or 128,   I can't run this program since it needs huge hardware !! Is there a way to make it with smaller hardware requirement?

Comment: @New_student For `n = 64`, your desired output matrix will have dimensions of `[64, 64, factorial(64)]`. Now, `factorial(64)` is something like `1.2689e+89`. That's a lot of memory you'll need, independent from the code generating this matrix. Do you actually need ALL possible permuation matrices at a single time point? Otherwise, you could iterate subsets of permutations. Or, as always when dealing with huge matrices, buy more RAM...

Comment: Is it possible to modify the answer to have them one by one ? @HansHirse

Comment: @New_student Ok, seriously: What do you actually want to do? You get factorial growth with increasing `n`. Already, for `n > 5`, the amount of matrices becomes impractical, for `n > 10`, it becomes just ridiculous. For `n = 10`, you get 3628800 matrices! Do you, conceptually, understand, that this task becomes somehow absurd? You talk about `n = 64`. What do you want to do with the resulting `1.2689e+89` matrices, these are I-don't-even-know-a-word-for-such-many-bazillions matrices. Of course, you could get the matrices one by one, but again, what do you actually want to do afterwards?

Comment: @HansHirse What I need to do is to multiply a matrix i.e Z with all possible permutation matrices and choose that permutation matrix which resulting a tr(Y) minimum; where Y is the results of multiplication of Z with the permutation matrix. I Think I don't need to generate all permutation matrices and store them in such variable, I can generate them one by one and get the result of multiplication. Is that possible ?

Comment: It is an interesting question, and it can be solved without generating all the possible permutation matrix, but it has nothing to do with your original question. Create a new question with all the informations above, explain that you're trying to find `m`, a permutation matrix, such that `trace(Z*m)` is minimized.

Comment: Your problem is called: the assignment problem and it can be solved with the [hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) in polynomial time.

Answer (score 2):

Using `repelem`, `perms` and `reshape`:

```
n   = 3;                                 % matrix size 
f   = factorial(n);                      % number of permutation
rep = repelem(eye(n),1,1,f)              % repeat n! time the diagonal matrix
res = reshape(rep(:,perms(1:n).'),n,n,f) % indexing and reshaping
```

Where `res` is:

```
res =

ans(:,:,1) =

   0   0   1
   0   1   0
   1   0   0

ans(:,:,2) =

   0   1   0
   0   0   1
   1   0   0

ans(:,:,3) =

   0   0   1
   1   0   0
   0   1   0

ans(:,:,4) =

   0   1   0
   1   0   0
   0   0   1

ans(:,:,5) =

   1   0   0
   0   0   1
   0   1   0

ans(:,:,6) =

   1   0   0
   0   1   0
   0   0   1
```

And according to your comment:

> What I need to do is to multiply a matrix i.e Z with all possible
> permutation matrices and choose that permutation matrix which
> resulting a tr(Y) minimum; where Y is the results of multiplication of
> Z with the permutation matrix. I Think I don't need to generate all
> permutation matrices and store them in such variable, I can generate
> them one by one and get the result of multiplication. Is that possible
> ?

You're trying to solve the assignment problem, you can use the well known [hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) to solve this task in **polynomial time**. No needs to generate a googleplex of permutation matrix.

Comment: how to apply that for the mentioned issue ? do you have any idea ?

Comment: Have you read the wikipedia article ? There is a step by step example.

Comment: Yes, I have checked it but I couldn't imagine how can I implement it for my issue!